# Brownian Motion Hitting Time of functions $y=t$ and $y=t^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $W(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion. Let $y(t)=t$. Define the following stopping time:

$T_h = \inf \{t>0: W(t)=y(t) \}$

What would be the probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(T_h\leq k)$$ for some constant $k>0$?

Now defining $y(t)=t^2$, what would be the probability?

Is there any literature on these types of problems? (I of course know how to compute the probability for the function $y(t)=constant$, but I haven't found any material for non-constant functions).

Comment: @Surb: apologies, I've corrected it now.

Comment: and what is the role of $h$ in $T_h$ ?

Comment: @Surb: $h$ just stands for "hitting time", just a convention I picked up a while ago, it can be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

On can prove the following proposition

> If $(W_s)_s$ is a Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, then
> $$
> \mathbb P\left\{W_t\in \mathrm d x,\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}W_s\in \mathrm d y\right\}=\frac{2(2y-x)}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}\right\}\boldsymbol 1_{(-\infty ,y]}(x)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y.
> \label{1}\tag{1}$$

Recall Girsanov theorem

> Let $(W_t)$ a Brownian motion and let $\theta \in L^2([0,T])$. Under the measure $$\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{\int_0^T \theta _s\,\mathrm d W_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T \theta _s^2\,\mathrm d s\right\}\mathbb P(\mathrm d \omega ),$$
> the process $$\tilde W_t:=W_t-\int_0^t\theta _s\,\mathrm d s,\quad t\in [0,T],$$ is a Brownian motion.

By Girsanov theorem, under the measure $$\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{W_t-\frac{1}{2}t\right\}\mathbb P(\mathrm d \omega )$$
the process
$$\tilde W_t:=W_t-t,$$
is a Brownian motion. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{T_h>t\}&=\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}(W_s-s)<0\right\}\\
&=\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}\left[\boldsymbol 1_{\left\{\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\tilde W_s>0\right\}}\exp\left\{-\tilde W_t-\frac{3}{2}t\right\}\right].
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}$ denote the expectation under the measure $\mathbb Q$. Using \eqref{1} allow you to conclude.

---

For $y(t)=t^2$, same idea using $$\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{2\int_0^ts\,\mathrm d W_s-\frac{2}{3}t^3\right\}\mathbb P(\mathrm d \omega ),$$
and the process $$\tilde W_t=W_t-t^2.$$ But at the end, I'm not so sure that you can find a nice closed form as the previous case.

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice answer. Just double checking: shouldn't the Radon-Nikodym derivative be $\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{W_t+\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$, instead of $\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{W_t-\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$?

Comment: No, but $\mathbb P(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\{-W_t+\frac{t}{2}\}\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )$, and indeed $\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}[...]$ I wrote is not correct. But I fixed it.

Comment: The PMF of $W_t-t$ under $\mathbb{P}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-(h+t)^2}{2t}\right\}$. Then, for some real number $a$, we have: $$\mathbb{Q}\left( (W_t-t) \leq a \right)=\mathbb{P}\left[ \exp \left\{ W_t+\frac{1}{2} t \right\} (W_t-t) \leq a \right]=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left\{ \frac{-h^2-2th-t^2+2ht+t^2}{2t}\right\}dh=\\=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left\{ \frac{-h^2}{2t}\right\}dh=\mathbb{Q}(\tilde{W_t}\leq a)$$ If I had used $\mathbb Q(\mathrm d \omega )=\exp\left\{W_t-\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$ instead, the result would not hold.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. It doesn't work like that. You have to use the proposition I put at the beginning of my answer. Moreover, you don't want to compute $\mathbb Q\{W_t-t\leq a\}$ but $\mathbb P\{\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}(W_s-s)<0\}$. @JanStuller

Comment: I tried to show that if we have $W_t$ as a Standard Brownian motion under the measure $\mathbb{P}$, then if we apply the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}=\exp\left\{W_t+\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$ to define a new measure $\mathbb{Q}$, then under $\mathbb{Q}$ we see that the distribution of $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t-t$ corresponds to a distribution of a Standard Brownian Motion. In other words: $\tilde{W_t}$ is a Standard Brownian Motion under $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @JanStuller: The proof is not obvious. You can find it in in the book of shreve and Karatzas : Brownian motion and stochastic calculs.

Comment: Isn't it just a question of algebra? The PMF of $W_t$ is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-(h)^2}{2t}\right\}$$. The PMF of $W_t-t$ is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-(h+t)^2}{2t}\right\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-h^2-2ht-t^2}{2t}\right\}$$. I can define event "A" as $$\mathbb{P}(A):=\mathbb{P}((W_t-t)<a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-h^2-2ht-t^2}{2t}\right\}dh$$. Then simply by definition of Radon-Nikodym, we have $$\mathbb{Q}(A)=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{dQ}{dP}\mathbb{I}_{A}]$$

Comment: the last equality evaluates to: $$ \mathbb{Q}(A)=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{dQ}{dP}\mathbb{I}_{A}]=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left\{ \frac{-h^2-2th-t^2+2ht+t^2}{2t}\right\}dh=\\=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left\{ \frac{-h^2}{2t}\right\}dh=\mathbb{Q}(\tilde{W_t}\leq a) $$ if we set $$\frac{dQ}{dP}=\exp\left\{W_t+\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but you look to confuse many things, and it' hard to follow you. The fact that $\tilde W_t$ is $\mathcal N(0,t)$ (under measure $\mathbb Q$) is indeed rather simple. But this won't prove that $\tilde W$ is a Brownian motion under measure $\mathbb Q$. As I said previously, the fact that $\tilde W$ is a Brownian motion under $\mathbb Q$ is not that obvious.

Comment: Ok, I apologise if I am not clear. But do you agree that $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t-t$ is $\mathcal N(0,t)$ under $\mathbb{Q}$ only if $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined via $\frac{dQ}{dP}=\exp\left\{W_t+\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$ and NOT via $\frac{dQ}{dP}=\exp\left\{W_t-\frac{1}{2}t\right\}$ ?

Comment: First, you don't have to apologize to anything :-) Moreover, I do not agree with your statement. $\tilde W_t$ is $\mathcal N(0,t)$ under $\mathbb Q$ with $\frac{\mathrm d \mathbb Q}{\mathrm d \mathbb P}=e^{W_t-\frac{1}{2}t}$. Notice $$\mathbb E^{\mathbb P}\left[\exp\left\{W_t+\frac{1}{2}t\right\}\boldsymbol 1_{\{\tilde W_t\leq a\}}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{-\infty }^{a+t}e^{x+\frac{1}{2}t}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}\,\mathrm d x.$$